# How to Create Lazy Loaded Feature Modules inside Angular 6 Library?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, ng-packagr, angular-library

I created a Library using Angular CLI 6 command.

Basically the Library is a Feature Module and it contains many child feature modules, connected through routing (Lazy Load).

I'm getting the below error at runtime

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "./contact/contact.module".
```

I tried all possible paths

```
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: 'contact.module#ContactModule' }
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: '/contact.module#ContactModule' }
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: './contact.module#ContactModule' }

{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: 'contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: '/contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: './contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }

{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: 'lib/contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }    
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: '/lib/contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: './lib/contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }
```

but nothing worked

Is angular library with ng-packagr is supported lazy loading?

Comment: plz provide app structure

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full file path starting from `app`

```
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: 'app/...../contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }
```

Please check [official guides](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use path from root folder and your app.routing should be placed in app folder
like src-app->app.routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: './app/...../contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }
```

Answer (score 0):

write path like:
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren:()=> contactModule }